# handler.postDelayed() is not executing

Tags: android, multithreading

So my problem is I can't get my handler to post after a certain amount of time. For some reason, it causes every button in the program to bug out and flash both of the colours. I'm open to suggestion and I am willing to switch up the code if something works better than handler. However, I would like to avoid using AsyncTask because I have no idea as to how to use it and it generally just pisses me off. Though I am willing to use it if absolutely necessary.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    random = new Random();
    random2 = new Random();

    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        while(running){
            ran = random.nextInt(9);
            type = random2.nextInt(3);

            if(lives > 0){
                if((type == 0 || type == 2)){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            buttons[ran].setImageResource(R.drawable.button_red);
                            buttons[ran].setTag("Red");

                        }
                    });
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(buttons[ran].getTag().equals("Red")){
                                buttons[ran].setTag("Black");
                                buttons[ran].setImageResource(R.drawable.button_null);
                                lifeLost();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }else{
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            buttons[ran].setImageResource(R.drawable.button_white);
                            buttons[ran].setTag("White");


                        }
                    });

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(buttons[ran].getTag().equals("White")){
                                buttons[ran].setTag("Black");
                                buttons[ran].setImageResource(R.drawable.button_null);
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
                if(score == 10){
                    duration -= 50;
                }else if(score == 20){
                    duration -= 50;
                }else if(score == 30){
                    duration -= 40;
                }else if(score == 40){
                    duration -= 15;
                }
            }else{
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        finished.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Intent overIntent = new Intent(this, OverActivity.class);
                    overIntent.putExtra("point", score);
                    startActivity(overIntent);
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                }catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Animator works.If necessary,you can use delay,instead of thead.

```
 protected ArrayList<ValueAnimator> mAnimators = new ArrayList<>();
protected Map<ValueAnimator, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener> mUpdateListeners = new HashMap<>();

private void initAnim(){
    final int[] delays = new int[]{0, 500};
    for (int i = 0; i < delays.length; i++) {
        final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(/*REd*/0xFFFF8080,/*Blue*/0xFF8080FF);

        animator.setDuration(800);
        animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.setTarget(i);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        animator.setStartDelay(delays[i]);//if necessary,you can use Delay;
        final int index = i;
        mUpdateListeners.put(animator, new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                btns[index].setBackgroundColor((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        mAnimators.add(animator);
    }
}


public void onStartAnimator() {
    if (mAnimators == null){
        initAnim();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mAnimators.size(); i++) {
        ValueAnimator animator = mAnimators.get(i);
        //when the animator restart , add the updateListener again because they was removed by animator stop .
        ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener updateListener = mUpdateListeners.get(animator);
        if (updateListener != null) {
            animator.addUpdateListener(updateListener);
        }
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Remember to finish the anim at the right time,such as `onDestroy` or `onDetachedFromWindow`!!!